# Convert bytes to string or store as bytes python

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption, crypt

I'm trying to encrypt string with python by RSA but the encrypted string returns as bytes
I'm trying to find a way either to convert bytes to string and store it in db or store it as bytes as it is but I couldn't find either of them
i use this project in django and mysql
i need some help on it and this is the full source code

```
import secrets
import string

import rsa


def create_token():
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    token = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(64))
    return token


def generate_keys():
    (pubKey, privKey) = rsa.newkeys(2048)
    with open('keys/pubkey.pem', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pubKey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))

    with open('keys/privkey.pem', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(privKey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))


def load_keys():
    with open('E:/workstation/projects/amon/cryptoPATH/keys/pubkey.pem', 'rb') as f:
        pubKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(f.read())

    with open('E:/workstation/projects/amon/cryptoPATH/keys/privkey.pem', 'rb') as f:
        privKey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(f.read())

    return pubKey, privKey


def encrypt_rsa(msg, key):
    return rsa.encrypt(msg.encode('utf-16'), key)


def decrypt_rsa(ciphertext, key):
    try:
        return rsa.decrypt(ciphertext, key).decode('utf-16')
    except:
        return False


def sign_sha1(msg, key):
    return rsa.sign(msg.encode('utf-16'), key, 'SHA-1')


def verify_sha1(msg, signature, key):
    try:
        return rsa.verify(msg.encode('utf-16'), signature, key) == 'SHA-1'
    except:
        return False


# generate_keys()
pubKey, privKey = load_keys()


def encrypt(msg):
    ciphertext = encrypt_rsa(msg, pubKey)
    return ciphertext


def decrypt(message):
    plaintext = decrypt_rsa(message, privKey)
    if plaintext:
        return plaintext
    else:
        return 'Could not decrypt the message.'


message = 'encrypted'
ciphertext = encrypt(message)
plaintext = decrypt(ciphertext)
print(str(ciphertext)[2:-1])

print(f'msg= {message}\n cipher= {ciphertext}\n plain= {plaintext}\n')
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: outputof code]

Comment: If you need to store encrypted data as a string then use something like base64 encoding to convert the encrypted data to a string. When you need to decrypt the data don't forget to base64 decode it before decryption.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks a lot your solution worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using base64 solved my problem

```
import base64
import secrets
import string

import rsa


def create_token():
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    token = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(32))
    return token


def generate_keys():
    (pubKey, privKey) = rsa.newkeys(2048)
    with open('keys/pubkey.pem', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pubKey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))

    with open('keys/privkey.pem', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(privKey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))


def load_keys():
    with open('keys/pubkey.pem', 'rb') as f:
        pubKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(f.read())

    with open('keys/privkey.pem', 'rb') as f:
        privKey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(f.read())

    return pubKey, privKey


def encrypt_rsa(msg, key):
    return rsa.encrypt(msg.encode('utf-8'), key)


def decrypt_rsa(ciphertext, key):
    try:
        return rsa.decrypt(ciphertext, key).decode('utf-8')
    except:
        return False


def sign_sha1(msg, key):
    return rsa.sign(msg.encode('utf-8'), key, 'SHA-1')


def verify_sha1(msg, signature, key):
    try:
        return rsa.verify(msg.encode('utf-8'), signature, key) == 'SHA-1'
    except:
        return False


generate_keys()
pubKey, privKey = load_keys()


def encrypt(msg):
    ciphertext = encrypt_rsa(msg, pubKey)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(ciphertext)
    return encoded.decode()


def decrypt(message):
    message = base64.b64decode(message)
    plaintext = decrypt_rsa(message, privKey)
    if plaintext:
        return plaintext
    else:
        return 'Could not decrypt the message.'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to store the cipher text (`bytes`) in a database is encoding it into a `string`. However, the challenge is that these [encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) could be perfectly valid in different `codecs` but could be very different when presented as strings:

```
import codecs
data = b'\xf0\xf1\xf2'  # three hex bytes [F0, F1, F2]
data.decode('latin1')  # Result: 'ðñò'
data.decode('cp1254')  # Result: 'ğñò'
```

You could maintain these as `hex` or [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#module-base64) encoded strings and decode them and use them as necessary.

```
import binascii
stored_data = binascii.hexlify(data)  # b'f0f1f2'
read_stored_data = binascii.unhexlify(stored_data)  # b'\xf0\xf1\xf2'

import base64
stored_data = base64.b64encode(data)  # b'8PHy'
read_stored_data = base64.b64decode(stored_data)  # b'\xf0\xf1\xf2'
```